# [solved]cannot use kinect on Ubt12.04 in virtual box

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

cannot use kinect on Ubt12.04 in virtual box

Ref: http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch#openni_launch.2BAC8-groovy.Quick_start

Since it took me quite some time to figure out how to get Kinect to work on VirtualBox(virtual machine) I thought to share it here with you.

My error is like the pic below:

[image: image description]

**My specs:**

```
Windows 7 running VirtualBox 4.3.28
Ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox
ROS Hydro
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215981/%5Bsolved%5Dcannot-use-kinect-on-ubt12.04-in-virtual-box/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2015-08-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2015-08-17**:
I refered this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819171/kinect-primesense-xtion-ros-ubuntu-through-virtual-machine-vmware
but not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use Kinect on Ubuntu with OpenNI（中文在后）

Please Refer [this blog](http://www.20papercups.net/programming/kinect-on-ubuntu-with-openni/) and you may meet some incompatible contents, do not worry, the thought and path is correct.

The very important doc you should read carefully is that on OpenNI's GitHub site and that on SensorKinect GitHub site.

```
The Core thing for this is Install Driver for Kinect on Ubuntu. The two important package you should install is:
The OpenNI UNSTABLE version
The SensorKinect package

Here, I want to say is that: after you have installed the OpenNI, and be ready to clone the git files for SensorKinect,DO NOT change directory!Otherwise you cannot generate the Redist directory for installation of SensorKinect.

The Cloning process could be very slow, you can checkout the files from here:
http://yunpan.cn/cmZEgEyrHdpMI  key_code: 73e3

There existed a Readme.txt file which is wriiten in Chinese. Don't worry, you can ignore it after you suffer this Installation for longer than 1 week cuz you will be the expert on this field at that time. ;-)

When you succeded in using Kinect_for_Windows on Ubuntu, the using of Kinect_for_Xbox is just 'unplug and plugin'.

It's Really easier if you use Kinect_for_XBox with OpenKinect. unfortunately, it does not support Kinect4Windows.

If you're using Virtual Machine launching Ubuntu on it, I don't recommend you continue. I failed too many times in trying to do it on VMs.
```

Read Carefully about This Blog: this blog. and follow it. Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) with karma: 287 on 2015-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2015-11-11**:
Above is the solution for this issue.